# Reaching Critical Mass

Tags: discussion

I just posted an idea in the chat for a *Weekly Challenge*, inspired by [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/629) meta discussion on the judaism.se site.

After some discussion, I was pointed [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/) to the site SO blog, discussing graduation, [area51 stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) etc. The main thing they look for is "Reaching Critical Mass", which looks like this:

[image: Suddenly it all takes off]

So I was thinking what idea did people have for getting us to reach critical mass?

Some ideas from this [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/own-your-community-2/) post.

- A Weekly challenge.
- An Answer-a-thon.
- Community promotion ads

Personally I think we'd benefit from more advertising on the forums of large <strike>gaming</strike> roleplaying sites, like [ENWorld.org](http://www.enworld.org/forum/), [RPG.net](http://forum.rpg.net/forum.php) and [Giantitp.com](http://www.giantitp.com/)

***What ideas do you have?***

Comment: +1 for advertising in RP sites

Comment: The question is how do we do this affectively?

Comment: Opening threads in said forums with links to some of our better questions that have been answered?

Comment: I fear that might smack too much of spamming the forums with stackexchange adverts.

Comment: I still think flyers at your local gaming shop is the best idea so far. Apart from that, we could design a forum signature for the site and people can have it in other forums, so people will notice.

Comment: @OddCore Go forth and post that as an answer!

Comment: Start browsing the site through http://holistic.xkcd.com!

Answer (score 7):

It has been suggested a few times that we give flyers to our local gaming shops to hand out or stick on the windows, and I still think that is the best idea so far. As far as online goes, the less intrusive way would be to design a forum signature that we can "wear" in any forum we like, so people can take notice and maybe attract more members this way.

Comment: I've had a link here in my RPG.Net signature for months.

Comment: Care to share? Is it an image or just text?

Comment: I'd say let's make it an image. With our name and picture, and then something like "got RPG questions?" and the signature itself will be a link to the site

Answer (score 3):

We need to start using our *Flairs* on some websites like ENworld.org and RPG.net.

[image: profile for Pureferret at Role-playing Games, Q&A for gamemasters and players of tabletop, paper-and-pencil role-playing games]

Comment: RPG.Net doesn't permit graphics in signature files.

Comment: And I've run into some issues using them on ENWorld too.